# Is it better to upscale lo-res or downscale hi-res versions of image that will be printed relatively small?

Tags: resolution, image-editing

I have two scans of a drawing. The scans have only black and white pixels in them. The higher resolution (HR) scan is is 1111 x 3882 pixels. The lower resolution (LR) one is 174 x 634 pixels. The largest this image will be printed is .55" x 2".  If I use the HR image, there are about 2000 dpi available. If I use the LR image, there are about 300 dpi.

It's a 1200 dpi printer. The LR image has to be upsampled to get to 1200 dpi. The HR image has to be downsampled to 1200 dpi. I know nothing about which program will do the up- or downsampling or how it will be done.

My general preference is to throw extra information away instead of making stuff up, so my instinct is to use the HR image, but I'm concerned that downsampling an image can introduce artifacts at small sizes. My goal is to have the best possible printed image.

Comment: (1) You neglect to mention the format of the images (e.g. raw or some compressed  format).  (2) Why agonize about the theoretical consequences?  Is it really that hard to perform experiments?  What are you doing while waiting for responses?

Comment: The images are PNG. As for experiments, I don't have access to the printer. The images will be printed remotely on ceramics using special toners. The people doing the printing may or may not have insight into this kind of question. I will ask them tomorrow. (Today is a holiday in the USA.) In the meantime, I thought there might be general insight that could help me decide how to proceed.

Comment: Then perform the experiment(s) and view the results on a monitor?  Since there are many [algorithms to choose from to perform upscaling and downscaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#Algorithms), some experimentation on the specific images you have might be better than relying on generic advice.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the hi-res version and downscale.    Depending on the way you downscale some programs may create grey-scale edges, but if you limit the number of colors to 2 this won't be an issue.